# How do I automatically update my page to add what is inputted? I am receiving TypeError

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am adding a recipes to page that has all recipes. When I add a recipe in my form the state is updated correctly. However, I have to refresh my all recipes page to have the newly added recipe show up. It keeps saying my id property is undefined.How would i fix it so it will automatically update?

render() {
    const { recipes } = this.props;

```
return (
  <div>
    {
      recipes.map(recipe => {
        return (
          <div key={recipe.id}>
            <Link to={`/recipes/${recipe.id}`} key={recipe.id}>
              <h2>{recipe.name}</h2>
            </Link>
            <div>{recipe.cuisine}</div>
            <img src={recipe.imageUrl} />
```

TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Comment: Iit is not your id that is undefined but your recipe. You must have an undefined value in your recipes array

Comment: Does a key of `id` exist on each  `recipie`?

Comment: inside `render`, add `console.log(recipes)` and look to see if there's an `undefined` item in the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding a defined recipe object.
`Console.log` your `props.recipes` and you will see, that the newly added one is `undefined` or `null`.
Check the function, which updates the recipe list and make sure, that a valid recipe is added to your list.